# Appending more than 1 element of different content into another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to append 2 div into 1 div, however, I can't manage to do so. No matter how I looked at my code, it seems correct. Here's what I have tried and done.

I am trying to accomplish this with the help of [ionic css components](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid-explicit)

```
Transaction ID | Payload
-------------------------
    1          |  ABC
    2          |  CDE
```

HTML

```
<ion-view view-title="List of Transaction ID(s)">
    <ion-content scroll="false">
        <div class="row">
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Javascript

```
$.ajax(settings1).done(function (response1) {
    var z = response1.transactions[0].uuid;
    var y = response1.transactions[0].payload;
    alert(z);
    alert(y);
    var row = document.createElement("div");
    row.className = "row";
    var col = document.createElement("div");
    var col1 = document.createElement("div");
    col.className = "col col-50";
    col1.className = "col col-50";
    col.innerHTML = document.createTextNode(z);
    col1.innerHTML = document.createTextNode(atob(y));
    row.appendChild(col);
    row.appendChild(col1);
});
```

Comment: You haven't appended `row` to an element in the document.

Comment: You have appended col and col1 to row but have haven't show how you inserted the row in your document...did your append the row to your html parent or body?

Comment: Oh shoots, silly me. Didn't manage to catch this small error.... very sorry!!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I know of to get data from an array into div(s) is to use an ng-repeat. I am assuming your List of Transaction IDs looks something like this:

```
"transactions":[
    {"transactionID":"1", "payload":"ABC"}, 
    {"transactionID":"2", "payload":"CDE"}, 
    {"transactionID":"3", "payload":"EFG"}
]
```

To easily display it you can use Angular's ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="transaction in transactions">
    <div class="row">
        {{transaction.transactionID}}
        {{transaction.payload}}
    </div>
</div>
```

You can strucure the data however you would like, but this create a div, with structured data, for all of the transactions that you have!